# How can I access mysql/mariadb server/db with NAppGUI SDK

Tags: c, user-interface, sdk

I could not figure out how to access my mariadb server with the NAppGUI SDK (https://nappgui.com/en/home/web/home.html).

I already have installed the required mariadb packages (libmariadb-dev and libssl-dev) for my linux distro (Linux Mint 21.1). Therefore mysql.h is located in "/usr/include/mariadb/mysql.h". It would be verry nice if I could for example just edit the main "nappgui_src/src/CMakeLists.txt" file to benefit from your excellent super build pattern.

Best regards Nejat

Comment: Maybe it's time to move to a modern GUI lib, try WebView https://github.com/webview/webview.

Comment: Can we see what you tried and what error messages you get?